# Is it possible to view files in a pod without using the kubectl exec command?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am using PostgreSQL in a pod on a self-hosted Kubernetes 1.23 (using Kubeadm). This pod was configured using the Helm Chart located at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/. I would like to be able to view files within this pod like individual log files (not the one exposed by *kubectl logs*) in order to find out what is wrong with the information being passed between my Entity Framework Core app and PostgreSQL.

However, this pod does not seem to have the ability to use *kubectl exec*, which is what I would normally use to view any file within a pod (and is how people seem to suggest doing so online). Is there a way to obtain a copy of or view the files within a pod running in Kubernetes without using *kubectl exec*, and if so, how would I do so?

Additionally, the storage is managed by Ceph, so I can't easily access the files from the node's filesystem.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not really clear. You want to exec to a pod while already inside of that pod?

Comment: Hi Paradoc welcome to SO. If you're self-hosted, jumping on the Node for that Pod is also a way to skip the `kubectl exec` cycle, since the Pod's filesystem is mounted on the host's filesystem

Comment: @Mdaniel, how would I access the pod's filesystem from the host? Additionally, I should mention it is using Ceph as storage, so that may not even be possible. I'll edit the post to add this.

Comment: Using ceph doesn't matter, since (docker|containerd) are just Linux namespace trickery -- they are mounted on disk regardless, and are visible via `mount`; the specific path will likely have `csi-` and the Pod's UUID in them, but (a) doing "ssh over SO comments" is painful, and (b) we have gotten **waaaaaaay** off-topic for a StackOverflow question. Feel free to ask your system administration question on ServerFault.com